# problems charts jquery highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want:

```
   var chart = new $('#Ejemplo').Highcharts.Chart(options_diputados);
```

i want creat chart in diferent div, i want especificate diferente div with same options.

any can help me?

Answer (score 2):

This

```
 var chart = new $('#Ejemplo').Highcharts.Chart(options_diputados);
```

is incorrect because you should use

```
//1
$('#Ejemplo1').highcharts(options_diputados);

//2
$('#Ejemplo2').highcharts(options_diputados);

//etc
```

or

```
 var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options_diputados);

 var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart(options_diputados);
```

Comment: i have the new problem, if there are two charts with diferent data, the firt $('#Ejemplo1').highcharts(options_diputados) is fine but second $('#Ejemplo2').highcharts(options_diputados) is the sum with firt, understand???

Comment: Use var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart($.extend({}, options_diputados);

 var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart($.extend({}, options_diputados);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Highcharts.setOptions()` to setup the default options, and change them individually if you need so, when creating the charts.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/setoptions/

Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.setOptions%28%29